# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Locale' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento-2.4.2/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php:64

Tags: magento2, error

I am using xampp and it's version is 7.4.15-0 and php version is 7.4.3.
I am trying to install magento version-2.4.2 in ubuntu linux and it's always say's Locale not Found.
[image]
I have enable the extension=php_intl.dll extension by removing the comment, but it still gives the same error. How should i solve it?
[image]

Edit(Solved)==>

I have solved this problem. This is happening because my terminal using usr/bin/php as default php, not the xampp php. So i have change the php path. To change the php path, please follow the link below
==> https://blog.shaharia.com/use-xampp-php-cli-in-your-command-line

Comment: did you restart PHP service?

Comment: Yes, i have done several times. Restart xampp several times. But it's giving error still

Comment: I have solved this problem. This is happening because my terminal using usr/bin/php, not the xampp php. So i have change the php path. To change the php path, please follow the link below  https://blog.shaharia.com/use-xampp-php-cli-in-your-command-line

Comment: good job! i suggest you add your solution as answer to your own question and mark it as solution so others see it too.